# How can I connect from Android to PC via USB?

Tags: android, usb

My ultimate goal is to have an app on my Android tablet connect to an app on my desktop via USB. I don't want to require my users to enable USB debugging- I have seen several implementations ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520989/android-httpclient-sending-request-to-host-machine-over-usb), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788811/how-can-i-initiate-an-android-to-pc-http-request-over-usb), [3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191930/Android-Usb-Port-Forwarding) ...) which use `adb` to handle data transfer, but that is unsatisfactory for my use case.

I followed the [USB Accessory guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html), and tried to list devices with:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    log( "Devices:" + manager.getDeviceList().toString() );
    ...
```

but the device list is always empty. `manager.getAccessoryList()` returned `null`.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.usb" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 <uses-feature
   android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" android:required="true" />
 ...
```

Later I tried `lsusb` on the device, in a terminal emulator and also in a `cron`'d script. It showed no devices connected. (I tried disabling USB debugging just in case- still nothing.)

Am I missing some permission for listing usb devices or do I need to configure my desktop to allow the UsbAccessory connection or what? If so, why would that prevent `lsusb` from showing the computer it's attached to?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to enable **USB tethering** on the tablet and then use TCP to connect your client and server.
See https://support.google.com/android/answer/182134?hl=en

Comment: That option does not appear in my settings menu. (I don't have a data plan for the tablet, does that matter?) Is there an API that I could use to initiate tethering from the app?

Comment: Re:[revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17603172/2) Yes, this instructs you to go to `Settings > Wireless & networks > Tethering & portable hotspot`, which does not exist on my tablet.